# how can I add weight to search term when searching by sphinx?

Tags: search, full-text-search, sphinx

how can I add weight to search term when searching by sphinx ?

example:

Assume that the users types this search:

" I'd like to play soccer (A.K.A football) "

and assume that I do some processing on this sentence to simplify it to "soccer football"

Now I want to give more weight to search results that have "soccer" than those having "football"

**How do I do that in Sphinx, please notice that I've seen answers here that mentioned that it's not possible, but I've seen an article about such possibility starting from sphinx 2.01 but it doesn't have further description**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate the term you would like to amplify.

```
->setMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED)
->setRankingMode(SPH_RANK_WORDCOUNT)
->Query('"soccer soccer soccer soccer football"/1',$index);
```